# Error pulling custom jupyterhub image in microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, jupyterhub, microk8s

I've created a custom Jupyterhub image with torch installed and pushed it to the local repository in localhost:32000 as mentioned in the microk8s documentation. When I create a release with the following helm chart, It cannot pull the image. The helm chart and errors are as follows :

```
hub:
  config:
    Authenticator:
      admin_users:
        - milad
      allowed_users:
        - abbas
        - hasan
    # ...
    DummyAuthenticator:
      password: password
    JupyterHub:
      authenticator_class: dummy
  db:
    type: sqlite-pvc
    upgrade:
    pvc:
      annotations: {}
      selector: {}
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      storage: 1Gi
      subPath:
      storageClassName: microk8s-hostpath
    url:
    password:

scheduling:
  userScheduler:
    enabled: false
  podPriority:
    enabled: true
  userPlaceholder:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 2

cull:
  enabled: true
  timeout: 3600
  every: 300

singleuser:
  image:
    name: localhost:32000/jupyter-torch
    tag: "registry"
  cpu:
    limit: 1
    guarantee: 0.5
  memory:
    limit: 1G
    guarantee: 512M
  profileList:
    - display_name: "GPU Server"
      description: "Spawns a notebook server with access to GPU"
      kubespawner_override:
        extra_resource_limits:
          nvidia.com/gpu: "1"
    - display_name: "CPU Server"
      description: "Spawn a notebook server with access to CPU only"
```

[image]